# Влияют ли комментарии на размер исполняемого файла после компиляции?

Tags: python, c

1. Влияют ли комментарии на размер исполняемого файла после компиляции ?
2. Влияет ли кол-во строк или символов на размер исполняемого файла после компиляции ?
3. `from time import sleep` или `import time`. Почему ?

Comment: Комментарии не влияют. Количество строк влиять может, если писать ну очень уж индусский код.

Comment: Определитесь, по какому языку у вас вопрос? 3 пункт вообще в отдельный вопрос лучше выделить.

Comment: Одинаково как для интерпретируемых языков, так и компилируемых ?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, а как выглядит "ну очень уж индусский код" ?

Comment: @Таня [Пример](http://www.ioccc.org/2011/akari/akari.c)

Comment: @dedifferentiator это надо изрядно знать язык, чтобы такое писать... :-)

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов скорее наоборот, чтобы так НЕ писать  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. "После компиляции" - значит язык компилируемого типа. У таких языков комментарии по определению (!) в исполнимый файл не попадают, они отбрасываются еще на этапе синтаксического разбора.
2. Если речь идет о строго одной и той-же программе, но можно предположить, что разница в количестве байт исходного кода может образоваться  при применении, например, в двух экземплярах кода, имен переменных разной длины. Такое различие на скорость выполнения не влияет. 
   Второй случай - "натыкано" много пробелов, например ( a + b ** c ) / d вместо 
   (a+b**c)/d  -  На скорость выполнения результирующего кода не влияет.
   Третий случай.  Строго одну и ту-же программу записали - в пределе - "лесинкой" или "в одну строчку". (Вполне может иметь место в том же С++). После компиляции они все равно превратятся в один и тот-же код, т.е. разницы в скорости исполнения не будет. Еще раз подчеркну - все это справедливо для компилируемых языков.
3. Это уже Python. Первый вариант применяется, если из всего множества функций пакета вам необходим только одна (в данном случае - sleep). Второй - если могут потребоваться несколько  функций пакета. Второй вариант может также приводить к конфликту имен из разных пакетов, т.е. быть источником определенного рода ошибок.

Answer (score 0):

В языке С:

1. Нет
2. Нет, если имеется в виду, что один и тот же текст разбивается на строки, например, или имена переменных  делаются иными. Очевидно, что программа из одной строки типа `puts("Hello");` будет меньше, чем программа, решающая какую-то серьезную задачу - в этом случае ответ Да. Естественно, рассматривая выполнимый файл без отладочной информации.
3. К С этот вопрос не относится.

Comment: Владимир прокомментировал по части Python ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Python - интерпретируемый язык. Насколько я знаю, в С не влияют.
2. Если вы меняете количество строк или символов, то вы меняете способ решения поставленной задачи, добавляете или убираете какие-либо действия, тем самым вы меняете размер исполняемого файла.
3. Я предпочитаю `from time import sleep`, т.к. так далее придется меньше писать. Но если пишете много, то лучше использовать `import time`, потому что если вы создадите свою функцию `sleep`, то они конфликтовать не будут, а если использовать `from time import sleep`, то выполняться будет ваша функция. Короче так меньше вероятность запутаться.

Comment: `from time import sleep` с одной стороны больше символов, чем `import time`, но так мы используем всего одну функцию из модуля (библиотеки). А когда `import time` - мы вызываем все функции из библиотеки, а это значит, что выгоднее всего использовать `from time import sleep`. Я правильно понимаю ? Или зависит не от самого факта импортирования всей библиотеки, а от количества использованных функций из библиотеки?

Comment: @Таня, эта тема тянет на отдельный вопрос, [здесь](http://qaru.site/questions/19019/import-module-or-from-module-import) неплохо написано про разницу между `from module import function` и `import module`.